# How to edit multiple xml files using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I tried to edit multiple XML files in a folder using python and was not able to replace the required one. This is the XML file and I need to replace the name with 'license_plate'. I tried the following code, but it is not replacing the name. I tried it in a loop as i have a number of XML files.

```
<annotation>
    <folder />
    <filename>N1.jpeg</filename>
    <path>/Users/asik/Desktop/ANPR/images/N1.jpeg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>1920</width>
        <height>1080</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>number_plate</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1093</xmin>
            <ymin>645</ymin>
            <xmax>1396</xmax>
            <ymax>727</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

```
import glob

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
dir = 'G:/YoloV7/annotations'

for xml_file in glob.glob(dir + '/*.xml'):
    mytree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = mytree.getroot()
    for elem in mytree.iterfind('object'):
        price = elem.findtext('name')
        new_price = str(price.replace(price, 'license_plate'))
        print(new_price)

mytree.write(xml_file)
```

Comment: Why not to use native XML API - XSLT for the task?

Comment: I am new to this and not familiarised with that one. Do we have any tuts ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `findtext()`, which just returns a string, try using `find()` instead...

```py
for elem in mytree.iterfind('object'):
    name = elem.find('name')
    name.text = 'license_plate'
```

Looks like you also need to indent your `mytree.write(xml_file)` line.

Comment: But when I use the find, i was not able to use the replace function that comes after that.

Comment: @RonyShaji - you shouldn’t need to do a replace(); just set the .text property to whatever the new value is supposed to be.